# Modal uiactionsheet ipad that cannot be dismissed

Tags: iphone, ipad, modal-dialog, uiactionsheet

How do I create an UIActionsheet on the iPad without having it dismissed by tapping the area around the action sheet? This is default on the iPhone, any luck on the iPad

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and I came up with a workaround more than a solution.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex);
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case -1:
            [self presentOptions];
    //.... more cases here
    }
}
```

When the user taps outside the **UIActionSheet** you get a **-1** as buttonIndex. In that case I presented the UIActionSheet again (by calling my method *presentOptions* that just presents the action). From the users perspective you can see a tiny blink un the UIActionSheet: hardly noticeable. Not a perfect solution but and acceptable workaround I'd say.

Comment: A few month late, but it's ok! Seems like a great answer. Haven't got a chance to test it out yet, but will do as soon as I get the chance. Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: Late indeed! Better late than never. I bumped into your question when trying to deal with the same problem!! It is a weird behavior on the iPad UIActionSheet.  cheers (fingers crossed for Neuromancer badge)